# yum install not working on Fedora

Tags: linux, virtualbox, fedora

I just installed fedora 17 on virtual box. I wanted to install KDE but get the following error

[image: Fedora 17 repo issue]

Now I tried removing the repo only to get this error

[image: After repo removal]

I have already commented `#mirrorlist=https` and uncommented `baseurl=http`
in the fedora.repo

Comment: Fedora 17 is EOL and packages are gone from mirrors. We have currently Alpha version of Fedora 24. Please, go and install something more recent. It is not safe to run such old system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fedora 17 is no longer supported, if you browse there and read the content of [this README file](http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/17/README) you will see you should use a recent versions of fedora or if you insist to use an out of date version, edit base url repository and use [this link](http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/17/)

Comment: I need to use fedora 17 as that is the requirement of the course I am taking. Can you tell me where is the man url (I am really new to linux)

Comment: Run this command `sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora.repo` and then replace `http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/$releasever/Everything/$basearch/os/` to lines that start with `baseurl`.

Comment: Once I replaced it in the updates and the fedora, testing and updates repo it works great. thanks a  lot.

Answer (score 0):

Test these things:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

If it does not work, you have a problem with your gateway or ip config (not set or done wrong).

```
ping google.com
```

If not working, you have problems with your dns servers (probably not set)